# Cakephp does not save dropdown list

Tags: cakephp, model, drop-down-menu, save

I have a relation Game belongsTo Type. In the add view of game, i see a dropdown list with the various types-title, which are VARCHAR in my table. But when I choose one and press save, it saves the ID of the type instead of the title(eventhough in my dropdown list I chose the title. When I create a game in PHPmyAdmin, everything works fine.
My code:

GameModel

```
class Game extends AppModel {

    public $name = 'Game';
    public $primaryKey = 'id';
    public $belongsTo =  array

     (
  'Type' => array (
        'className' => 'Type',
        'foreignKey' => 'type_id'
     ));
```

add function in GameController

```
 public function add() {
$types = $this->Game->Type->find('list',array('fields' => array('title')));
$this->set('types',$types);

    if ($this->request->is('game')) {
        if ($this->Game->save($this->request->data)) {
            $this->Session->setFlash('Your game has been created.');
            $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash('Unable to add your game.');
        }
    }
}
```

add view of Type

```
    <h1>Add Game</h1>
<?php
echo $this->Form->create('Game',array('action' => 'edit'));
echo $this->Form->input('tablename',array('rows' => '1'));
echo $this->Form->input('date');
echo $this->Form->input('type_id');
echo $this->Form->end('Save Games');
?>
```

I hope someone can find a solution. If any more information are requiered, pls dont hesitate to ask.

Thank you in advance and best wishes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//Add function in your controller

$types= $this->Game->find('list', array(
    'conditions' => array('Game.type_id'),
    'fields'     => array('Game.id', 'Game.title')
));
$this->set(compact('types'));

// view
echo $this->Form->input('type_id', array(
    'type'    => 'select',
    'options' => $types,
    'empty'   => false
));
```

Comment: sry just found that I used "types_id" instead of type_id, but now I have the next problem, but many thanks for your extremly fast response!! can you help me with my new problem?

Comment: Sure, what's the new problem?

Comment: I edited the initial post! Just read the first couple of lines. Practically it saves the ID of my Type instead if the title (VARCHAR). Eventhough in my Dropdown I can see the titles for choosing. Table is corectly formatted, if I create a Game in PHPmyadmin, everything works fine.

Comment: This doesnt work. There is now Game.title in my database. Maybe I expressed myself not correctly. I would like to have the title of the Type shown in my Games column types_id.

Comment: In the conditions field you have to do a sql statement of whatever you're calling. So for this you would want the type_id WHERE the foreign key of the type_id is equal to the type. Then, the Game.id and Game.title will relate to how you want to display the select box.